# Multi-part Regular Expression

Tags: regex, expression

I have the requirement to restrict a  non-required textbox to only numbers (0-9) with a separator of ';'.  The pattern is that the groups can be 4 or 5 in length and can repeat n times.  Anything less than 4 in a group is invalid.  After 4 or 5 I need to check for the existence of a separator character ';'.  This pattern can repeat n times.  I have tried variations of but this doesn't seem to be working.   Something simple to start out like

```
[0-9]{4,5};+
```

is invalid as I don't need the separator for only 1 number grouping.

Next I tried

```
^[0-9]{4,5}|[0-9]{4,4};|[0-9]{5,5};$
```

but this doesn't work because the existence of four digits like 1111 or five digits 11111 before gives one match before it goes awry example "11111;j"  Is there a way in a regex to validate

```
1111
11111
1111;1111
11111;1111
11111;11111
```

but catch

```
111
111;
1111;1
11111;1
abc
```

in a repeating fashion?

Comment: What is the languge/tool?

Comment: Not clear what is required. Absence of good examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This validate your examples.

```
^[0-9]{4,5}(;[0-9]{4,5})?$
```

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/PhVf87/1)

It's not clare what you mean by "in a repeating fashion". If you want validate also this

```
1111;11111;11111;1111;11111
```

You can use this regex

```
^[0-9]{4,5}(;[0-9]{4,5})*$
```

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/hpXz1u/1)

Comment: Your assumption was correct.  I have to account for nothing entered, one 4-5 digit entry or an indeterminate number of entries that are 4 or 5 digits in length and separated by a semi colon.